# Keeping an IEnumerable and an ObservableCollection in sync

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, repository-pattern

Short version:

I have two collections: an `IEnumerable` and an `ObservableCollection`. I need a way to keep them in sync. That means, if any item is added, deleted or updated in one, that item and only that item will automatically be added, deleted or updated in the other as well. How can this be done?

Long version:
I am using `Entity Framework` with `WPF`. Since I am implementing repository pattern with `MVVM`, the `ViewModel` only gets `IEnumerable` of entities. I need them to be converted to `ObservableCollection` without losing the ability of `change tracking` provided by `Entity Framework`.

I have scoured the net looking for the solution, but in vain. Is there any way to do it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case, there is not general solution to the problem.

That said. You aren't using `IEnumerable`. You are using `DbSet<T>`, which exposes `public ObservableCollection<T> Local { get; }`. Solution. Don't synchronize two collections. Just use the correct collection to begin with.

EDIT re question:

I would refactor your code so that the "Repository" is the Collection.

```
public class FooRepository
    : ICollection<Foo>
    , INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    private BarDbContext _context;

    public FooRepository()
    {
        _context = new BarDbContext();
        _context.Foos.Local.CollectionChanged += (o, e) => CollectionChanged(this, e);
    }
    //Delegate ICollection to _context.Foos.Local
    public Foo this[int index] { get { return _context.Foos.Local[index]; } }

    public Task Load(Expression<Foo, bool> predicate)
    {
        return _context.Foos.Where(predicate).LoadAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: A naive question here: Suppose, I am doing this in my repository:
`IEnumerable<T> FindWhere(expression<func<T,bool>> predicate)
{ return context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToList(); }`
In other words, I am eager loading. If I want to use Local, am I supposed to load explicitly using Load()?

Comment: Your edit might've worked if I had only one method in my repository. However here is only a part of it. How am I supposed to handle it here?

`public T FetchByPrimaryKey(object primarykey)
        {
            return _ctx.Set<T>().Find(primarykey);
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> FindWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _ctx.Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToList();
        }

        public T FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _ctx.Set<T>().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
        }`

Answer (score 2):

Keeping track of `ObservableCollection` changes is trivial; the class - more specifically, the interface it implements - has a `CollectionChanged` event you can subscribe to. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) for info on this event and its event args.

An `IEnumerable`, by definition, is just a collection that you can enumerate over. It has no equivalent "change" concept because there is no business with it other than looping through it/filtering it. If you're stuck with `IEnumerable`, then the responsibility of change notifications has to be moved up a level to whatever is maintaining the collection.

Comment: Although everything you wrote is correct. A more careful reading of the question shows that `IEnumerable` is actually EntityFramework. In which case the solution is simple. You just use the `DbSet<T>.Local` property.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the clarification.